# How to access environment variables in custom script extension script on Azure

Tags: azure, environment-variables, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-templates

I have created a RHEL Linux VM and installed Oracle JDK in it.

Post creation of VM, I am executing script using Custom Script extension in VM. Below is my script.

**Myscript.sh**

```
echo "$$ $JAVA_HOME $$" >> output.log
echo `env` >> output.log
```

**output.log**

```
$$ $$
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin PWD=/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/1 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SHLVL=4 _=/usr/bin/env
```

When I ran the above script, I don't see JAVA_HOME is set. But I see JAVA_HOME value when I logged into the machine.

**Update:-**

During installation of Oracle JDK, I set JAVA_HOME in /etc/profile.

**script1.sh**

```
javaHomeValue=$(cat /etc/profile | grep JAVA_HOME | awk -F= '{print $2}')
```

echo " -- $javaHomeValue -- " >> output.log

**output.log**

```
-- /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172-amd64 --
```

I am able to get JAVA_HOME using the above script1.sh

Is there any reason, Why JAVA_HOME is not set in environment variables during execution of Custom script?

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, if you want to set JAVA_HOME as environment variable in file /etc/profile, you can add code `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172-amd64` into /etc/profile. Then you can see the environment variable JAVA_HOME in a new terminal.

Comment: How would i add environment variable in scale set linux instances (auto scaling enabled)?

Comment: @lambad I will suggest you change the image with the environment variables already set in it.

Comment: If I manually add environment variables in profile file and generalize and create image then all the added environment variables will be destroyed as a result I won't be able to access them.

Comment: @lambad When you generate the VM, it will delete the home directory, so you can set the environment variables in another path. I will suggest set them in the /etc/environment file.